# Number of ways to divide 2n points into equal halves with a single line

Tags: plane-geometry, computational-geometry

If there are an even number of points in a plane, assuming no three are collinear, how many ways can they be divided into equal halves by a line? This would be counting the number of possible partitions of the points, and not the (infinite) number of lines.

Further, on what conditions does collinearity of points reduce this quantity?
In the extreme case, when all points are along a line, there's only one way to split them: down the middle.
Is there some inductive method that can be used to determine this quantity given all the points?

Comment: two points are always collinear. maybe you mean not 3 of them

Comment: By the way, even with 4 points, the number of partitions depends on their configuration (may be 2 or 3, even with no collinearity)

Comment: @BenChislett You may be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem It is not your problem, but a related one. The problem was posed in 1893, solved in 1944. Some interesting developments on generalizations are still being made, even as recently as 2013: https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4714

Comment: Thanks Exodd. I meant 3

Comment: What you‘re asking is an instance of the so-called k-set problem, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-set_(geometry) . The bounds on these numbers are a notorious open problem in discrete geometry. As for a lower bound, It is easy to show that you must always have at least n different ways of halving the point set and that there are point sets where there are exactly n ways. However, for upper bounds it is only known that there are at most O(n^(4/3)) ways and that there are point sets with more than nlogn ways (see the link for the exact bounds).